# GCP Zero BLEU score

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-automl, automl, bleu

Is it normal that for a trained Italian translation model gcp does not count the BLEU score?

[image: screenshot of GCP BLEU score for IT & FR languages]

Comment: One possible case for this is a configuration issue; that the dataset is actually in a different language.

Answer (score 0):

If the BLEU score is zero, one possible case is that the dataset is actually in a different language. A configuration issue.

You would nee to verify whether your dataset matched with the selected language, i.e. Italian.